# Include Header File in _Layout Page

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to include a header file in my _Layout.cshtml page in asp.net core MVC application. The header.cshtml is located under root folder under wwwroot\inetpub, not under ~\Views\Shared\ , ie. \include\header.cshtml. I have tried to use @Html.Partial("/include/header"), @Html.Partial("/include/header.cshtml"), but I get error for "InvalidOperationException: The partial view '/include/header' was not found. The following locations were searched: /include/header". Please advise.

Comment: Views should be in the Views folder

Comment: Is there a way to include a file in the razor view page not in the Views folder? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use relative paths, like this:

```
@Html.Partial("../../wwwroot/include/header")
```

Here is the directory structure:

[image]

Comment: This question can be: how to include a file outside of the project folder to the _layout razor page. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the file you want to include is outside the project? It doesn't make sense to do it, why would you do it?

Comment: If you must do this, you can use [IFileProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: We have global header and footer files for all applications and those files change sometimes. That's why I need to include files outside of the project folder. I will take a look at the IFileProvider. Thanks.